# Where do I find product ID variable for Adroll script

Tags: javascript, magento, adroll

I'm trying to modify an Adroll script and don't know where to find the product id variable need for the script.

I'm not a coder but have been able to find solutions for almost everything on stackoverflow but have not found an answer to this one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  adroll_custom_data = {"product_id":YOUR PRODUCT ID VARIABLE}
</script>
```

To learn what the product variable is and how to use it.

Comment: Do you have a list of products and IDs by chance? If so then just put whatever number or string you want there

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, MikeK! I added the adroll tag to your question so more users who knows the system you're using may be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks but adding individual ID is not practical. We have about 1100 items in our magento site. I'm supposed to place the code in all the product pages below the Adroll smart pixel we already have installed in the footer. Replace the corresponding product ID variable in the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

if you have magento- adroll has an integration for magento 1.5 and up https://help.adroll.com/hc/en-us/articles/214799358-Magento-1, would be way easier to use that instead of placing the pixel manually.

if you still choose to place the pixel manually, the product ID variable will need to match the product ID provided in the feed. if you have the feed handy, you can look at one product's corresponding ID, and match the value to your site's setup.  this variable and its corresponding instructions will vary based on the magento version, and there's a magento stackexchange that has answered similar questions.

lastly, feel free to write in to support@adroll.com where someone will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. We did in fact use the integration tool from Adroll and that is why I was a bit surprised when we got the request to add this new code. I will reach out to our rep and see what it going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated Adroll in Magento ver 2.3.4.This is value should I pass for **product_id** on the product detail page.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> adroll_custom_data = {"product_id": "PASS THE PRODUCT ID VARIABLE"};
> </script>
> ```